# How can I add multiple Ansible variables onto a single line in a csv file?

Tags: bash, ansible

I have this playbook that gather information about a server using command like df, free, sar. sorry I am very new too ansible.

Here is the playbook I am using.

```yaml
- name:
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name:
      shell: df -h
      register: mount
    - name:
      shell: free -h
      register: ram
    - name:
      shell: echo "{{ mount.stdout }}" "{{ ram.stdout }}" >> prechecks.csv
      delegate_to: localhost
```

The outcome I get is this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G   10M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        18G   11G  6.8G  63% /
/dev/sda1       295M  288M  7.2M  98% /boot
tmpfs           372M  1.2M  370M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs           372M  5.7M  366M   2% /run/user/0
tmpfs           372M  4.0K  372M   1% /run/user/1001 total        used          free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:          3.6Gi       1.5Gi       904Mi        18Mi       1.2Gi           1.9Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

As you can see the memory information is under the mount filesystem. Is there a way I can get them like this?

The way I want them to be:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on     total used free shared buff/cache available                        
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev               Mem: 3.6Gi 1.5Gi     904Mi 18Mi 1.2Gi  1.9Gi
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm           Swap: 2.0Gi  0B                        
tmpfs           1.9G   10M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        18G   11G  6.8G  63% /
/dev/sda1       295M  288M  7.2M  98% /boot
tmpfs           372M  1.2M  370M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs           372M  5.7M  366M   2% /run/user/0
tmpfs           372M  4.0K  372M   1% /run/user/1001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [paste](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) command.  Here is what would result using the outputs you provided in your question:

Combined using paste:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on    total        used          free      shared  buff/cache   available
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev  
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm  Mem:          3.6Gi       1.5Gi       904Mi        18Mi       1.2Gi           1.9Gi
tmpfs           1.9G   10M  1.9G   1% /run  Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup    
/dev/sda3        18G   11G  6.8G  63% / 
/dev/sda1       295M  288M  7.2M  98% /boot 
tmpfs           372M  1.2M  370M   1% /run/user/42  
tmpfs           372M  5.7M  366M   2% /run/user/0   
tmpfs           372M  4.0K  372M   1% /run/user/1001
```

There is an empty line included in the `free` command output in your source data but your desired output does NOT include that empty line.  You can remove the empty line by using `sed '/^$/d' < <(free -h)` instead of `free -h`.  Output after removing the empty line:

```
$ paste df.out mp.out
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on    total        used          free      shared  buff/cache   available
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev  Mem:          3.6Gi       1.5Gi       904Mi        18Mi       1.2Gi           1.9Gi
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm  Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
tmpfs           1.9G   10M  1.9G   1% /run  
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup    
/dev/sda3        18G   11G  6.8G  63% / 
/dev/sda1       295M  288M  7.2M  98% /boot 
tmpfs           372M  1.2M  370M   1% /run/user/42  
tmpfs           372M  5.7M  366M   2% /run/user/0   
tmpfs           372M  4.0K  372M   1% /run/user/1001
```

---

contents of df.out:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G   10M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        18G   11G  6.8G  63% /
/dev/sda1       295M  288M  7.2M  98% /boot
tmpfs           372M  1.2M  370M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs           372M  5.7M  366M   2% /run/user/0
tmpfs           372M  4.0K  372M   1% /run/user/1001
```

contents of mp.out

```
total        used          free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:          3.6Gi       1.5Gi       904Mi        18Mi       1.2Gi           1.9Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Comment: To get a really nice double-column look, OP can also pipe it to `column`. `paste <(df) <(free -h) | column -s $'\t' -t`

Comment: Thanks @j_b and kamilCuk. This has solved my question